# how to make openldap search from root of directory tree

Tags: search, openldap

I am new to this site. Please help me with a query on openldap search.
I dont want to provide info like "base dc=example, dc=com" in ldap.conf. I want to give only host and port info in ldap.conf
Can we make openldap client to search from root of the directory tree?

If I dont add any line for "base" in ldap.conf, and search for a valid user,  the Active server gives search response as "no such object"

Is there some other way to acieve always search from root, without filling explicitly "base dc=xxx, dc=yyy" in ldap.conf on client side?

Answer (score 0):

Bad luck, you have to provide the base.

I don't understand your objection to a one line entry in a configuration file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Can we assume root of search base for ldap server of an organization with domain name example.com will be (which we need to provide in ldap.conf):
dc=example, dc=com

Or can the base be like:
dc=ldap, dc=example, dc=com

Comment: No, you can't assume that. It can be whatever the guy who installed it decided. You can however interrogate 'namingContexts' attribute of the root element to see what DIT(s) it supports.

Comment: Thank you once again for valuable inputs.